# Convert dictionary of lists of tuples to list of lists/tuples in python

Tags: python, hash-map

I've got dictionary of lists of tuples. Each tuple has timestamp as first element and values in others. Timestamps could be different for other keys:

```
dict = {
            'p2': [(1355150022, 3.82), (1355150088, 4.24), (1355150154, 3.94), (1355150216, 3.87), (1355150287, 6.66)],
            'p1': [(1355150040, 7.9), (1355150110, 8.03), (1355150172, 8.41), (1355150234, 7.77)],
            'p3': [(1355150021, 1.82), (1355150082, 2.24), (1355150153, 3.33), (1355150217, 7.77), (1355150286, 6.66)],
}
```

I want this convert to list of lists:

```
ret = [
            ['time', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3'],
            [1355149980, '', 3.82, 1.82],
            [1355150040, 7.9, 4.24, 2.24],
            [1355150100, 8.03, 3.94, 3.33],
            [1355150160, 8.41, 3.87, 7.77],
            [1355150220, 7.77, '', ''],
            [1355150280, '', 6.66, 6.66]
]
```

I'm making conversion with that dirty definition:

```
def convert_parameters_dict(dict):
    tmp = {}
    for p in dict.keys():
        for l in dict[p]:
            t = l[0] - l[0] % 60
            try:
                tmp[t][p] = l[1]
            except KeyError:
                tmp[t] = {}
                tmp[t][p] = l[1]
    ret = []
    ret.append([ "time" ] + sorted(dict.keys()))
    for t, d in sorted(tmp.iteritems()):
        l = []
        for p in sorted(dict.keys()):
            try:
                l.append(d[p])
            except KeyError:
                l.append('')
        ret.append([t] + l)
    return ret
```

Maybe there is some much prettier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
times = sorted(set(int(y[0] / 60) for x in d.values() for y in x))
table = [['time'] + sorted(d.keys())]
for time in times:
    table.append([time * 60])
    for heading in table[0][1:]:
        for v in d[heading]:
            if int(v[0] / 60) == time:
                table[-1].append(v[1])
                break
        else:
            table[-1].append('')
for row in table:
    print row
```

Or, less readable but probably faster if the dictionary is long (because it only loops through each list in the dictionary once):

```
times = sorted(set(int(v2[0] / 60) for v in d.values() for v2 in v))
empty_row = [''] * len(d)
table = ([['time'] + sorted(d.keys())] + 
         [[time * 60] + empty_row for time in times])
for n, key in enumerate(table[0][1:]):
    for v in d[key]:
        if int(v[0] / 60) in times:
            table[times.index(v[0] / 60) + 1][n + 1] = v[1]
```

Comment: Thank you all. Stuart, I'll use your second solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
            'p2': [(1355150022, 3.82), (1355150088, 4.24), (1355150154, 3.94), (1355150216, 3.87), (1355150287, 6.66)],
            'p1': [(1355150040, 7.9), (1355150110, 8.03), (1355150172, 8.41), (1355150234, 7.77)],
            'p3': [(1355150021, 1.82), (1355150082, 2.24), (1355150153, 3.33), (1355150217, 7.77), (1355150286, 6.66)],
} 

ret = pd.DataFrame({k:pd.Series({a-a%60:b for a,b in v}) for k,v in d.iteritems()})
```

returns

```
              p1    p2    p3
1355149980   NaN  3.82  1.82
1355150040  7.90  4.24  2.24
1355150100  8.03  3.94  3.33
1355150160  8.41  3.87  7.77
1355150220  7.77   NaN   NaN
1355150280   NaN  6.66  6.66
```

It is not a list of lists, but using pandas you can do much more with this data (such as convert the unix timestamps to datetime objects with a single command).

Comment: Wow, now that is slick!